# Dealing with missing property/keys in AJAX GET JSON request

Tags: ajax, json

Sometimes JSON object called from an AJAX request will be missing the key/property of the value I want to display in a table. The problem is when a key is missing it causes a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" to be logged in the console and breaks my code. I tried using a || statement but that didn't work. See code snippet below:

```
function getNextObject() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://scrapi.org/object/" + randomNum,
    success: function(data) {
      var timeline = data.timelineList[0].name || "not available";
      var medium = data.medium;
      var culture = data.culture;
      var geo = data.geography;
      var date = data.dateText;
      var gallery = data.galleryLink;
      var title = data.title;
      var artist = data.primaryArtist.name || "not available";
      var image = data.currentImage.imageUrl;
```

PrimaryArtist and timelineList are not always contained in the JSON object throwing an error and causing code to break. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code is trying to get the `.name` of these variables and the variables themselves are probably empty.

You could build an `if` around the variables `timelineList` and `primaryArtist`

How about you try these replacements:

```
var timeline = data.timelineList ? data.timelineList[0].name : "not available";
...
var artist = data.primaryArtist ? data.primaryArtist.name : "not available";
```

Comment: or `data.primaryArtist && data.primaryArtist.name ?data.primaryArtist.name : "not available";` to ensure the name is present also...but same net effect as the ternary operator is the way to resolve this most easily.